AutoInclude works only on one Navigation Property
I have create a simple Database: One from "Parent" To "Child" and one to "Parent" from "Reference".
I create a new ParentItem, add some Childs and some References. All Associations are Bi-Directional and Many:Many. I save the ParentItem to DB and it works. All Data is writen in the Tables
When I read the ParentItem from the DB then the Child-Property is filled. The References-Property is empty.
Here is the GetEntityParent-Code:
public EntityParent GetEntityParent(long EntityParentId)
{
    EntityParent serverEntityParent = null;

    using (EFModelDatabase _DbContext = new EFModelDatabase(DbOptionBuilder.Options))
    {

        try
        {
            serverEntityParent = _DbContext.EntityParent.Single(EntityParent => EntityParent.Id == EntityParentId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception _exception = ex;
        }

        return serverEntityParent;
    }
}

Here is my Model:
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChild>()
            .ToTable("EntityChild")
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChild>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>()
            .ToTable("EntityParent")
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>()
            .HasMany<EntityChild>(p => p.Childs)
            .WithMany(p => p.ParentChild)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(right => right.HasOne<EntityChild>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EntityChild_Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),left => left.HasOne<EntityParent>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EntityParent_Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),join => join.ToTable("ParentToChilds"));
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>().Navigation(e => e.Childs).AutoInclude();

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityReference>()
            .ToTable("EntityReference")
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityReference>()
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityReference>()
            .HasMany<EntityParent>(p => p.ParentRef)
            .WithMany(p => p.References)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(right => right.HasOne<EntityParent>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EntityParent_Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),left => left.HasOne<EntityReference>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("EntityReference_Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),join => join.ToTable("RefToParent"));
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityReference>().Navigation(e => e.ParentRef).AutoInclude();


Please turn this into a [mre]. I.e. remove the irrelevant classes and show the c# class definitions that remain so we can reproduce this issue.

I have upload a working MSTest-Project to reproduce the problem. In the Folder "NestedEntities" you find my Test-Class. The Methode "ModifyChildReferenceEntities" show the problem
link

Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. Questions should be self-contained and not depend on transient external sources.
